# crystal report formula to filter between dates for bar chart

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I get an error when I try to add parameters to filter between dates in a crystal report selection record formula. This is the formula I used:

```
if {tblFaultyDevice.date} >= {?dateFrom} and {tblFaultyDevice.date} <= {?dateTo} then true
```

Error:

> A string is Required Here

Comment: What is the datatype of date database field and also parameters

Comment: ohh ok where did you write that formula? in which window?

Comment: Crystal report, select expert, record formula.. am trying to filter between dates, i passed in two paremeters which are dateFrom and dateTo. when ever try to launch i get that error.. i found a way to stop the error but by using ToText{?dateFrom} vice versa. the error stoped but yet the chart does not pick the date i pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have written is wrong.. select expert record selection doesn't accept any boolean values to return.

your formula should be:

```
{tblFaultyDevice.date} >= {?dateFrom} and {tblFaultyDevice.date} <= {?dateTo}
```

Comment: what is the best way to pass date paremeters to crystal report chart and filter between dates?

Comment: code you have wrote is correct can you show your select expert window, can you paste the screen shot

Comment: I guess  your database field `{tblFaultyDevice.date}` is a string datatype and its not date datatype.

Comment: the error is not there any more.. i dont know how to add picture to post here.. the other issue i have at the moment is that when i perform the filter no data on the chart is displayed

Comment: see that is your problem.. your database field and your parameter datatypes are not matching... either you convert the database field compatable to parameters or make parameter dataype compatable to database.

Comment: To add picture take the image and save on local system.;. then use ctrl+G on Stack overflow then attach the picture in your question

Comment: so how do i do that in this case now?

Comment: what is your {tblFaultyDevice.date} data type? and what is your parameters datatype.

Comment: If both are date datatype then my solution should work... I have no idea why its not working.

Comment: the formula is working but it does not filter the chart.. what else am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ok do one thing take the query from report and fire the same on database and check whether you are getting any data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80995/discussion-between-umar-e-shaibu-and-siva).